# How to use FIRApp.createUserWithEmail in specific database reference?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Iv been converting my post Firebase 2 codebase to Firebase 3 and having some troubles.

So basically Im trying to figure out how I create a new user at a specific location on my Firebase DB.

Goal - I want to save all new users @ `var _USER_REF = FIRDatabaseReference().child("\(BASE_URL)/users")`

Here is the code so far.

```
class  DataService {

    static let dataService = DataService()

    let BASE_URL = "https://project-1321.firebaseio.com"
    var _BASE_REF = FIRDatabaseReference().child(BASE_URL)
    var _USER_REF = FIRDatabaseReference().child("\(BASE_URL)/users")
    var _NEWS_REF = FIRDatabaseReference().child("\(BASE_URL)/news")
    var _MARKET_STATS = FIRDatabaseReference().child("\(BASE_URL)/market")

    var CURRENT_USER_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {

        let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String
        let currentUser = FIRDatabaseReference().child("\(_BASE_REF)").child("users").child(userID)
        //let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)
        return currentUser

    }



    func createNewAccount(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        _USER_REF.child(uid).setValue(user)
    }



}

View Controller

@IBAction func registerAccount(sender: AnyObject) {

        guard let email = self.emailRegField.text where !self.emailRegField.text!.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        guard let username = self.usernameRegField.text where !self.usernameRegField.text!.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        guard let password = self.passwordRegField.text where !self.passwordRegField.text!.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password) {
         (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                self.signUpErrorAlert("Alert", message: "There was a problem signing up!")
            } else {

                let user = ["provider": user?.providerID, "email": email, "username": username]

                DataService.createNewAccount(user) // Doesnt Work

                }



                //Store UID in NSDefaults so if user reopen app they automatically log in if UID exsisits.
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result ["uid"], forKey: "uid")

                // Segue New User

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newUserSegue", sender: nil)

        }
```

// Loggin in a User who already has UID Saved to NSDefaults

When a user log's in or Registers I plan to save their "UID" to NSDefaults.

Then check like so :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") != nil {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newUserSegue", sender: nil)
        } else {
            print("User is not registered or has their UID saved to NSDefaults")
        }

    }
```

Is this a safe method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@brkr In response to your comment above, you can still use the UIDs in order to add unique users to your Firebase database.

For example, here is your users ref (in the DataService Class):
`let REF_USERS = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("\(URL_BASE)/users")`

Now, create a user in Firebase 3.0:

```
FIRAuth.auth()!.createUserWithEmail(email, password: pwd, completion: { authData, error  in
            if error == nil {    
                // Log user in
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: pwd) { authData, error in
                    // Save user information to Firebase data
                    let user = // your user Dictionary 
                    DataService.createNewAccount(authData!.uid, user: user)
                }
            } else {
                // Handle login error here
            }
        })
```

The code for the create account method:

```
func createNewAccount(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    REF_USERS.child(uid).setValue(user)
}
```

Comment: Awesome man. Thank you!! I did everything as you said but for some reason i cannot use the `createNewAccount` method in my view controller. See image - http://imgur.com/a/obfR1

Comment: Nvm I had to add `DataService.dataService.createNewAccount`

Comment: Actually Im tring to save the UID to NSUserDefaults so it will auto login later on but it prints NIL for some reason. Have any idea? See image - http://imgur.com/K8wlylO

Comment: Im not completely sure it's `nil`. Perhaps try authData?.uid.

Comment: Yep that worked :). Iv updated the post at the bottom..Is that a safe way to check if the user is already logged in? I dont want the user to have to login everytime they close the app.

Comment: As far as I know that's the way to do it. That's one of the main uses for NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is necessary with new Firebase, look in the Dashboard, all your users should be under "Auth" tab,

Also this line doesnt make any sense in new Firebase, the URL you are querying is in the .plist you downloaded.

```
let BASE_URL = "https://project-1321.firebaseio.com" //remove this line
```

**and use something like this**

```
let firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let newsRef = firebaseRef.child("news")
```

you can find many useful informations here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password

Comment: So are you saying that I no longer need add a UID to each user so its unique? If I save the "email" and "password" in the "Auth" tab how can i save additional information. For example say if the user sign up form has 5 fields. "Username" "Email" "Password" "Alias" "Location". I would use "Email" and "Password" in the `createUserEmail` method and I would have to use `setValue` to save all 5 fields into the "Users" directory?